# What characters are permitted for a slug in noir?

Tags: clojure, noir, clout

I have a Clojure service that I'm exposing via REST.  I have a page defined as:

```
(defpage "/package_versions/:id" {:keys [id]}
  (do
    (println "ID: " id)
    (if-let [pv (pv/fetch-one (db/keyspace) id)]
      (response/json pv)
      (response/status 404 nil))))
```

What characters are allowed for id?  The slugs 1-2-3, 1|2|3, 1_2_3 all work, but 1.2.3 doesn't. Is there a way to make slugs which contain . work?  What are the allowed characters in noir routes?  Which code is responsible for this behavior: noir, ring, compojure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Clout test cases](https://github.com/weavejester/clout/blob/master/test/clout/test/core.clj).

The slugs used in the tests don't really have special characters in them so I don't know what characters are legal, but at the end of the file there's an example of how to define a custom route matcher that presumably can be used to match dots if you so desire.

I would expect that you can plug the custom route matcher into Noir with either `noir.core/compojure-route` or `noir.core/custom-handler`.

Also, there are tests with literal dots in them, e.g. `"/foo.:ext` that matches URLs like  `/foo.txt`, so I wouldn't be surprised if it was a feature, not a bug, to not allow dots in slugs.

Comment: So your right, I also posed this question to the clj-group 

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/clj-noir/KbrxJrafUrU

And they referred me to this guide:  https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki/Routes-In-Detail

Comment: So the relevant part of that document is: `The :id part will match any sub-path up to the next "/" or "."`. It also states that you can specify your custom regex for sub-path matching inline, e.g. `(defpage ["/user/:id", :id #"[0-9]+"] ...)` in the case of Noir.

Answer (score 0):

It should be [`clout`](https://github.com/weavejester/clout) responsible for this, which is a library Compojure uses. You can have a look at [`wakeful`](https://github.com/flatland/wakeful/blob/develop/src/wakeful/core.clj) to see one example of setting up different matchers, in particular the use of `route-compile`.